# Problem with creating log files in Delphi

Tags: delphi, logging

What I want to do basically is to write log files for my VCL app. Logging procedure has to create text file on given location with name that will contain current date of writing, example is "BSSGLog 20231106.txt". In order to make it easier to go through the log files if needed I wanted to limit the entries to 1000 lines of text. If there is overflow on that current date then it has to create new file with added extension, example "BSSGLog 20231106_1.txt" etc. It works fine until it reaches extension "_9", after that it creates file with extension "_10" but it only writes one line of text and creates "_11". It keeps creating files with only one line of text until it reaches "_89". After that it works fine again. I know that the problem lies in procedure *SearchFiles* because it keeps checking the file with extension "_9" over and over again. This is the code to make it more easier to understand what I wanted to do.

```
function SearchFiles(SearchDir, SearchFile: string):String;
var
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst(SearchDir + SearchFile, faAnyfile, SearchRec) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      Result := SearchRec.Name
    until (FindNext(SearchRec)<>0);
  end;
  FindClose(SearchRec);
end;

procedure Log(s: string);
var
  FileCont: TStringList;
  FileName, LogEntry: String;
  fs: Tformatsettings;
  i: Integer;
begin
  DeleteFilesOlderThan30Days;
  if not DirectoryExists(TPath.GetHomePath() + '\test') then
    CreateDir(TPath.GetHomePath() + '\test');
  if not DirectoryExists(TPath.GetHomePath() + '\test\Logs') then
    CreateDir(TPath.GetHomePath() + '\test\Logs');
  FileCont := TStringList.Create;
  try
    fs.ShortDateFormat := 'YYYYMMDD';
    fs.TimeSeparator := ':';
    if SearchFiles(TPath.GetHomePath() + '\test\Logs\', 'BSSGLog ' + DateToStr(now,fs) + '.txt') = '' then // I believe the problem lies here
      begin
        Filename := TPath.GetHomePath() + '\test\Logs\BSSGLog ' + DateToStr(Now, fs) + '.txt';
        fileCont.SaveToFile(filename);
      end
    else
      Filename := TPath.GetHomePath() + '\test\Logs\' + SearchFiles(TPath.GetHomePath() +
                  '\test\Logs\', 'BSSGLog ' + DateToStr(now,fs) + '*.txt');
    FileCont.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    if FileCont.Count >= 1000 then
      begin
        i := GetFilesCount(TPath.GetHomePath() + '\test\Logs\', 'BSSGLog ' + DateToStr(now,fs) + '*.txt');
        Filename := TPath.GetHomePath() + '\test\Logs\BSSGLog ' + DateToStr(Now, fs) + '_' + i.ToString + '.txt';
        FileCont.Clear();
      end;
    fs.ShortDateFormat := 'DD.MM.YYYY. HH:mm:ss';
    LogEntry := DateTimeToStr(Now(), fs) + '- ' + s;
    FileCont.Add(LogEntry);
    FileCont.SaveToFile(Filename);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(FileCont);
  end;
end;

function GetFilesCount(SearchDir, SearchFile : String) : Integer;
var
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if FindFirst(SearchDir + SearchFile, faAnyFile xor faDirectory, SearchRec)= 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      Inc(Result);
    until (FindNext(SearchRec) <> 0);
    FindClose(SearchRec);
  end;
end;
```

Any advice would be highly appreciated. Maybe an idea of how to do a better job at logging. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Consider writing at least up to 10k or 20k lines in one logfile, 1k is not very much!

Comment: I thought about it but in my app there is rarely a case when more then 3 files are created for given date, so it makes it easier to go through them when checking the log. Thank you for recommendation though!

Comment: Take a look at [LoggerPro](https://github.com/danieleteti/loggerpro). It's FileAppender class implements log rotation, maxsize and maximum number of files. All what you want!

Comment: When you are logging something into a log file you want this process to be as fast as possible. So you don't want to be performing multiple file searches each time you are logging something. Why? The bigger the number of files you have in specific directory the longer will each file search take. So do yourself a favor and store filename of your last log file in some string variable. This way you can reuse that information for each subsequent write.

Comment: As for naming of log files when you have multiple log files for single day. Instead of adding `_1` etc. I recommend you add `_01` as extension to filename instead. Why? Windows Explorer sorts file by their string representations and not by their numbers. Meaning that if you have let's say 22 numbered files their order would be `File_1, File_11, File_12, File_13, File_14, File_15, File_16, File_17, File_18, File_19, File_2, File_21, File_22`. So looking at those split logs won't be very intuitive. But adding leading zeros will avoid that problem.

Comment: @SilverWarior I've considered what you are saying, that is why I am deleting files older then 10 days, I've left that part of the code out because of its irrelevance to this question, but thank you, useful information nonetheless. Renaming with 01. 02 is a good idea, totally overseen how File Explorer sorts out files. I appreciate your answer very much, kind man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get rid of the function `SearchFiles`, because of the ordering problem and you should take advantage of the `FileExists` function. Taking your code in account, this is how would I modify it:

```
try
  fs.ShortDateFormat := 'YYYYMMDD';
  fs.TimeSeparator := ':';
  i := 0;
  Filename := TPath.GetHomePath() + '\test\Logs\BSSGLog ' + DateToStr(Now, fs) + '.txt';
  if not FileExists(Filename) then 
  begin
    fileCont.SaveToFile(filename); // doesn't exist; create it
  end
  else
  begin
    if FileExists(TPath.GetHomePath() + '\test\Logs\BSSGLog ' + DateToStr(Now, fs) + '_1.txt') then
    begin 
      i := GetFilesCount(TPath.GetHomePath() + '\test\Logs\', 'BSSGLog ' + DateToStr(now,fs) + '_*.txt');
      Filename := TPath.GetHomePath() + '\test\Logs\BSSGLog ' + DateToStr(Now, fs) + '_' + i.ToString + '.txt'; // get the last file
    end;
  end;
  FileCont.LoadFromFile(FileName);
  if FileCont.Count >= 1000 then
  begin
    Filename := TPath.GetHomePath() + '\test\Logs\BSSGLog ' + DateToStr(Now, fs) + '_' + (i+1).ToString + '.txt';  //new file
    FileCont.Clear();
  end;
  fs.ShortDateFormat := 'DD.MM.YYYY. HH:mm:ss';
  LogEntry := DateTimeToStr(Now(), fs) + '- ' + s;
  FileCont.Add(LogEntry);
  FileCont.SaveToFile(Filename);
finally
  FreeAndNil(FileCont);
end;
```

I didn't tested it. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: That's just what I needed. Simple yet adequate solution for this problem. Works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. This solution works only if there are no log files deleted. If you want to take that into account then you should think of using FindFirst/FindNext procedures in a loop and finding the last file in this loop using the TSearchRec.Timestamp. Or think of better file naming and sorting the files found.

Answer (score 0):

In `function SearchFiles(SearchDir, SearchFile: string):String;` you go through the search results and output the last file matching the criteria. How ever this may not be the last file created. The order of the files is not defined, you should collect all the file names, examine them and decide witch one is the last and output it.

See [Is FindFirst supposed to return found files in Alphabetical order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595727/is-findfirst-supposed-to-return-found-files-in-alphabetical-order)

Comment: Thank you for answering Julius. I've seen that FindFirst doesn't sort the files, good to know. I've also seen the *GetOrderFiles()* procedure in that post you've linked but to be honest, I'm not sure how to implement that here.

Comment: @q1werty your log filenames contain dates in them.  Simply parse the filenames to extract the dates so you can sort the files by date.  If 2 files have the same date, then parse out and compare the number that follows the date.  You can do all of this with a `TStringList` using a `TStringList.CustomSort()` comparer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Adding that kind of sort kinda bothers me a bit, we also have to check number of entries in each file for the current date and take the one with <1000 lines. Maybe a bit overengineered? It is a solution nonetheless. Thank you for your answer Remy!

Comment: Are you searching for files every time you log something new? This is something you should only be doing once at startup. Figure out the last file, then open it and keep it open. Count what's in it and keep track of that. Once you reach 1000 lines, choose the file and start a new one and reset the counter. Even better, save this information somewhere on shutdown so you can just reload it next time and not have to hunt for it